# read incoming image in asp classic page sent from android

Tags: android, asp.net, asp-classic

i am sending image via android phone to server , but the server script is in asp classic page which is responsible for reading binary image data and storing it into sql server database.

from android i am sending image using POST method named "file" but in asp classic page its not able to read the POST method parameter.

how can i read the incoming binary data in asp classic page ?

i am sending it using

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

String fileName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DB.DIST_IMG_URL));

multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("file", bitmapdata,ContentType.create("image/jpeg"),fileName);
```

if any one can share links to sample for asp classic then it would be much helpful

Comment: If you post (update the question) the ASP code we might be able to help further...

Comment: When you say you are not able to read the POST parameter, are you trying to read the uploaded file or a form field parameter. How are you trying to read the parameters? You can't use Request.Form with multipart/form-data.

Comment: @John If the OP posts the code for the ASP page it would definitely clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Classic ASP upload component or one of the pure Classic ASP upload scripts. There are many available of either.

For a free pure ASP upload script (no installation of components needed) you can use [this one](http://www.taka.nl/programming/asp/pseudorequest/default.asp).

A component is quicker for anything other than small files. You may want to check if your web hosting company has one already installed you can use... many hosts do.

Comment: I might of read it wrong but didn't the OP say they already had a script the problem is it isn't working? In either case the OP needs to show that script if they want more help.

Comment: Well they said they weren't able to read the POST parameter. Maybe they aren't reading it right, or now that I think about it they might be trying to read it with Request.Form which isn;t going to work with multipart/form-data. I will ask.

Comment: If they are trying to read it multipart/form-data with `Request.Form` I can't see how it ever worked. Should be using `Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)` to parse it or some other Upload COM component as you suggest in your answer.

Comment: I don't think the OP said that it ever worked. They are asking how to do it, no?

Comment: Probably just found this statement a bit misleading *"server script is in asp classic page which is responsible for reading binary image data and storing it into sql server database"*...sounds like they already had something in place.

Comment: Maybe some day in the near future you and I will stop speculating amongst ourselves about this and the OP will respond :)